# Does creating a method for each small functionality in Java deteriorates performance?

Tags: java, android, performance, oop, design-patterns

I work on Android and Java almost all the time. I am still at an intermediate level of experience in both. But whenever I code, I try follow and implement all the **OOP** concepts while programming even for small applications or programs.

> **I have a question that does creating a METHOD for each functionality (data passing, data retrieval, calling subroutines in other classes,
>   activities) is a good practice or a bad practice? And does creating
>   lot of methods(modules) degrade performance?**

Any sort of help or explanation is truly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#PreferStatic) and [this](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#GettersSetters), making more and more methods for everything is not a good idea in Android. In their words, "virtual method calls are expensive". They also recommend avoiding excessive use of design patterns and class hierarchies; see [here](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#Abstractions) and [here](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#DependencyInjection).

Comment: Thanks for the links. It did help me to get detailed explanation.